# $gte and $lte not working with node.js/mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, date, mongoose

I am simply trying to count some documents. When using other parameters such as "type": "someType", I get the correct count. But when I use `{"createdAt": {"$gte": "", "$lte": ""}}` (with actual dates which are JS date objects) I get 0 as the count. Been at this for days now, and I can't seems to find the solution...

I tried narrowing the case down to the smallest reproducable possible. Like so:

```
  const query = {
    createdAt: {"$gte": new Date("2023-11-01"), "$lte": new Date("2023-11-30")},
  }

const result = await Entity.countDocuments(query)
```

This returns 0, even though I know for 100% that I have documents matching the critera, with e.g. "createdAt": '2023-11-06T08:09:07.000Z'.

Trying the same countDocuments() function with other parameters returns correct number, for instance:

```
  const query = {
    tags: {"$nin":["false-positive", "out-of-scope"]},
  }

const result = await Entity.countDocuments(query)
```

The above will return the correct number of documents which does not have these two strings in its "tags"-field.

I have also tried using the "$and" operator, like so:

```
  const testQuery = {
    $and: [{ createdAt: { $gte: new Date("2023-10-01") } }, { createdAt: { $lte: new Date("2023-11-31") } }],
  }
```

But with no luck.

I have also tried logging out the query with the operators, and pasting it into MongoExpress "Advanced"-tab. This returns the correct documents, so the issue seems to be with Mongoose or Node.js.

I have no idea why it is not working with the "$gte" and "$lte", please help.

EDIT: I found one work-around, but it should not have to be necessary. In order to make it work, I had to perform the exact same query against the collection itself, rather than using the DB-model "Entity":

```
const colletion = mongooseConnection.collection("colecctionName")

const result = await colletion.countDocuments({ createdAt: { $gte: "2023-10-01", $lte: "2023-11-31" } })
```

This gives me the correct count, but I don't see why it shouldn't work with the DB-model itself.

EDIT 2: Made it work well enough by using `new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0]` so we only get the YYYY-MM-DD format. This along with querying the collection directly, instead of using the DB model allows me to pull data between dates.

Allthoguh, the question remains. Mongoose is supposed to handle JS date-objects, and it seems overly limited that we cannot specify date any further than within a day.

Comment: What gives `{ createdAt: { $gte: '2023-11-01', $lte: '2023-11-30' } }`? I think you can just pass the string. You also have quotes around `$gte`and `$lte`, remove them too.

Comment: @KurtVandenBranden { createdAt: { $gte: '2023-11-01', $lte: '2023-11-30' } } gives the same result; 0 from Node.js - 3 documents directly in MongoExpress. The quotes around `$gte` and ´$lte´ are not there in the code, just added by habit when I made the question ^^

Comment: What does the model look like?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method, this how I do handle it

```js
import * as dateFns from 'date-fns';

class Helper {

  public static generateDateRange(obj, dbType = 'NoSQL') {
    try {
      const dateRange: any = JSON.parse(obj);
      if (dateRange && dateRange.startDate && dateRange.endDate) {
        const startDate = dateFns.startOfDay(dateFns.parseISO(dateRange.startDate));
        const endDate = dateFns.endOfDay(dateFns.parseISO(dateRange.endDate));
        return dbType === 'NoSQL' ? { $lte: startDate, $gte: endDate } : Between(startDate, endDate);
      }
      return Helper.generateSingleDateRange(dateRange.startDate || dateRange.endDate || new Date(), dbType);
    } catch (e) {
      throw Helper.generateSingleDateRange(obj, dbType);
    }
  }
  
  public static generateSingleDateRange(date, dbType = 'NoSQL') {
    const startDate = dateFns.startOfDay(dateFns.parseISO(date));
    const endDate = dateFns.endOfDay(dateFns.parseISO(date));
    return dbType === 'NoSQL' ? { $lte: startDate, $gte: endDate } : Between(startDate, endDate);
  }
}


const startDate = new Date('2023-01-01'); // Replace with your start date
const endDate = new Date('2023-12-31'); // Replace with your end date
const query = { createdAt: Helper.generateDateRange({ startDate, endDate })}

const result = await Entity.countDocuments(query)
```